# SQLite 'ON CONFLICT' not working on some versions

Tags: sql, sqlite

I'm working in a plugin environment where I have the SQLite drivers available at runtime. However I recently started writing some SQL statements that take benefit from the 'ON CONFLICT' feature, this worked all fine. But I noticed that during time and with different versions of the SQLite driver that feature (on conflict) was not working properly, or it was not present at all. It works fine from 3.25.2 and above, which is what newer version of the software I'm working with provide, however when I try to bring support for older version, which shade the 3.21.0.1 driver, i get a SQL syntax error near 'on conflict'. This is the statement:

```
INSERT INTO data(player_uuid, player_name, flags_domains, flags_ipv4, flags_words)
      VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?)
      ON CONFLICT(player_uuid)
      DO UPDATE SET flags_words = flags_words + 1, player_name = ?;
```

As said before it does work properly on the newer drivers, I've even tried searching something on the SQLite changelog website, but I didn't find a reason for it to not be working, anyone knows how could I would work around the 'on conflict'?

Comment: It works from version 3.24.0 : https://www.sqlite.org/lang_UPSERT.html

Comment: Thank you very much for this information, however I'm pretty new to SQLite so I wouldn't know how one would write a statement that allows to do the same thing but without the 'ON CONFLICT' feature. Would I need to use multiple statements?

Answer (score 1):

If your version of SQLite does not support UPSERT, you can do what you want with 2 statements.

First update:

```
UPDATE data
SET flags_words = flags_words + 1, player_name = ?
WHERE player_uuid = ?;
```

If the value of `player_uuid` exists in the table then the row will be updated.
If it does not exist nothing will happen.

Then try to insert with `INSERT OR IGNORE`:

```
INSERT OR IGNORE INTO data(player_uuid, player_name, flags_domains, flags_ipv4, flags_words)
VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?);
```

If the value of `player_uuid` exists in the table nothing will happen.
If it does not exist then the new row will be inserted.